# Resign First Responder On Push To Detail

Tags: swift

I was wondering how to resignFirstResponder whenever I switch to my detailView in the tableView, is this something I can implement in my prepareForSegue or somewhere else.

Here is my prepareForSegue code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewLemon
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let Make = self.resultSearchController.active ?
                filteredTableData[indexPath.row] as String  :
                tableData[indexPath.row] as String
            VC.sentData1 = Make
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any `UIView` (and `UIWindow` as well, as it is `UIView` subclass) has method

```
func endEditing(force: Bool)
```

This will resign any current first responder descendant in the hierarchy of the view on which you call this method.
So you can call it on the view of the previous detail view controller or at the whole application's window from the prepareForSegue or any other logic point of your program.

Comment: Where would you implement this in my code. @DisableR

Comment: If I knew your code - I tell you :) Basically, in viewWillDisappear of the detail controller - if question is about resigning of first responder on detail controller.